# How to find the period of $\cos(\sin(\sin(x)))$?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I know the fact that the period of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ functions is $2\pi$. My teacher taught me how to find period of $\sin2x$. But I'm interested in how to find the period of nested functions like period of:

- $\sin(\sin(x/3))$
- $\cos(\sin(\sin(x/3)))$

**I tried this method:**

$\sf Period \,of \,\sin(x/3) = \dfrac{Period \, of \, \sin(x)}{Coefficient\,of\,x \, in\, function}$

$\implies 6\pi$

But how to find period of $\sin(f(x))$ where period of $f(x) = 6\pi$?

Same like this, I stuck on $\sin(\sin(x/3))$.

Please help me, I'm trying to solve it since yesterday but I'm still unable to figure it out.

Comment: Try x+$\pi$ in your function

Comment: Try thinking about the meaning of a period rather than a formal "method".

Comment: @EthanBolker I do understand what you are saying. But, understanding the meaning of period won't tell us the period of cos(sin(sin(x/3))).

Comment: The first sentence in @AdamNeeley 's answer is the answer. What does the definition of periodicity tell you when you know the period of the innermost function in the composition?

Comment: @EthanBolker sorry but I'm just a beginner to this topic. I just know about the period is that it is the tendency of a function to repeat its value after a specific interval. Am I right to say this? Answer of Adam Neeley answers that the period of function sin(sin(x/3)) is same as sin(x/3) but what about the period of cos(sin(sin(x/3)))? Is it same as the period of sin(x/3)?

Comment: @Utkarsh Yes, If you add the period of the innermost function to  $x$ then the innermost calculation returns the same number. That same number is passed up the chain and nothing else can change.

Comment: @EthanBolker Period of sin(x/3) is $6\pi$. So period of sin(sin(x/3)) will also be $6\pi$. But how to add it in the next chain for cos(x)?
`cos(6pi+x)` => Are you referring like this? Period of cos(sin(sin(x/3)) is given to be $3pi$.

Comment: Last comment. The last calculation is not $\cos(6\pi + x)$. It's $\cos\sin\sin((1/3)6\pi + x)))$.

Comment: @EthanBolker If I am not mistaken the period of $\cos(\sin(\sin(x/3))$ is $3\pi$ because $\sin(\sin(x/3))\in [-\sin(1),\sin(1)]$ and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ implies we have half the period.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the period of $\cos(\sin(\sin(\frac x3)))$ be $P$, where $P>0$ is the smallest value satisfying the equation $$\cos(\sin(\sin(\frac x3)))=\cos(\sin(\sin(\frac {x+P}{3})))$$ **for all values of $x$**.
$$\implies \sin(\sin(\frac x3))=\pm\sin(\sin(\frac {x+P}{3}))+k\cdot2\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Due to the range of $\sin$ this equation has no solution unless $k=0$. So now we solve
$$\sin(\sin(\frac x3))=\pm\sin(\sin(\frac {x+P}{3}))=\sin(\pm\sin(\frac {x+P}{3}))$$

So **either** $$\sin(\frac x3)=\pm\sin(\frac {x+P}{3})+k'\cdot 
2\pi,k'\in\mathbb{Z}$$
**or**
$$\sin(\frac x3)=\pi\mp\sin(\frac {x+P}{3})+k'\cdot 
2\pi,k'\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Again, due to the range of $\sin$, we must have $k'=0$ in each case, and for the same reason we can ignore the second pair of cases.

So we are reduced to solving $$\sin(\frac x3)=\pm\sin(\frac {x+P}{3})=\sin(\pm\frac {x+P}{3})$$
$$\implies \frac x3=\pm\frac{x+P}{3}+k''\cdot2\pi,k''\in\mathbb{Z}$$
**or**
$$\frac x3=\pi\mp\frac{x+P}{3}+k''\cdot2\pi,k''\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Of these four options, only two can be valid **for all** values of $x$, i.e. the ones where $x$ is eliminated:

The first one with a $+$ sign gives $$-\frac P3=k''2\pi\implies P=6\pi$$

And the second one with a $-$ sign gives $$0=\pi+\frac P3+k''2\pi\implies P=3\pi$$

So the period is $3\pi$.

You might like to try the first one yourself.